# scale down kubernetes deployments to 0 and scale back to original number of replica sets

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, kubernetes-deployment

I have written a bash script to get  all deployments on a kubernetes cluster.
I have a command to scale all the deployments to zero.
The challenge I am having is that, I want to be able to loop through all the deployments and save their name and number of replicas so I scale them back to the original after scaling down.

How do I achieve that?
This is what I have done so far.

```
$ kubectl get deployments
$ kubectl scale deploy -n default  --replicas=0 --all
```

Comment: If you want to scale up immediately after scale down, `kubectl rollout restart` is the better option.

Comment: [eberz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370484) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66252689) saying "I have implemented a bash script for this. Please check it out: https://gist.github.com/evertonberz/93ec7c445fbd13ae9e0abc585eabd2d2"

Answer (score 29):

You could annotate resources for the previous state of replications. Then you could use the below commands to change replicas.

```
# annotate first 
kubectl get deploy -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"kubectl annotate --overwrite deploy "}{@.metadata.name}{" previous-size="}{@.spec.replicas}{" \n"}{end}' | sh

# scale to 0
kubectl scale --replicas=0 $(kubectl get deploy -o name) 

## scaleback 
kubectl get deploy -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"kubectl scale deploy "}{@.metadata.name}{" --replicas="}{.metadata.annotations.previous-size}{"\n"}{end}' | sh
```

Comment: @Emre Oodabaş
care to explain how does it work?

Answer (score 2):

You could save the output into a bash array:

```
declare -A arr
for i in $(kubectl get deployment -o name)
do
  arr+=( [$i]="$(kubectl get $i -o=jsonpath='{.spec.replicas}')")
done
```

And then use that again to scale up:

```
for key in ${!arr[@]}
do
  kubectl scale deploy $key --replicas=${arr[${key}]}
done
```

Answer (score 2):

First get a list of all deployments, this is important, because you need it to scale back up when needed:

```
kubectl get deploy -A --no-headers | grep -v 'kube' > deploy_state_before_scale.txt
```

Scale all non k8s system related deployments to 0:

```
kubectl get deploy --no-headers -A | grep -v 'kube' | awk '{print $1}' | while read  DEPLOY; do kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment/$DEPLOY -n $DEPLOY; done
```

To scale cluster back to how it was before you scaled to 0. Make sure to use 'deploy_state_before_scale.txt' that was created before scaling to 0:

```
awk '{print $1,$4}' deploy_state_before_scale.txt | while read DEPLOY SCALE; do kubectl scale --replicas=$SCALE deployment/$DEPLOY -n $DEPLOY; done
```